# Don't export variable changes to sub-make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

makefile1.mk

```
MYVARIABLE += change1

$(info var MYVARIABLE: $(MYVARIABLE))

all:
    make -f makefile2.mk
```

makefile2.mk

```
MYVARIABLE += change2

$(info var MYVARIABLE: $(MYVARIABLE))

all:
```

**I have this two makefiles, when I run them output I get is:**

Running:
`make -f makefile1.mk`

```
var MYVARIABLE: change1
var MYVARIABLE: change2
```

Running:
`MYVARIABLE=term make -f makefile1.mk`

```
var MYVARIABLE: term change1
var MYVARIABLE: term change1 change2
```

**What I want to achive:**

`MYVARIABLE=term make -f makefile1.mk`

```
var MYVARIABLE: term change1
var MYVARIABLE: term change2
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#:%7E:text=Variable%20values%20of%20the%20top,(see%20Summary%20of%20Options).) for a description of how make passes variables down to a sub-make

In short, variables can be exported or non-exported.   If a variable is exported, its current value is passed to the submake.  If it is non-exported, then nothing is passed to the submake.

By default, if you create a variable in the makefile (and do not use the `export` keyword), then the variable is not exported.   If, however, you define the variable from the environment, then that variable is considered exported, and the sub-makefile will see its original value, and/or any changes made to that value.

In your specific example, if you specify `MYVARIABLE` in the environment, then it is exported, and therefore, when you add `change1` to it, then `term change1` is passed to the submake (and `MYVARIABLE += change2` simply adds to this known value).   If you do not specify `MYVARIABLE` on the command line, then in makefile2.mk `MYVARIABLE` starts of as undefined, and `MYVARIABLE += change2` simply sets it to `change2`.

You can explicitly unexport a variable, but this would not do what you want, as the submake would not see the `term` value specified in the environment.  I would suggest using a seperate variable to differentiate what's specified in the environment and what you want to set it to for the local makefile:

makefile1.mk:

```
_MYLOCALVARIABLE := $(MYVARIABLE)
_MYLOCALVARIABLE += change1

$(info var _MYLOCALVARIABLE : $(_MYLOCALVARIABLE))

all:
        make -f makefile2.mk
```

makefile2.mk:

```
_MYLOCALVARIABLE := $(MYVARIABLE)
_MYLOCALVARIABLE += change1

$(info var _MYLOCALVARIABLE : $(_MYLOCALVARIABLE ))

all:
```

Answer (score 1):

Harry's answer of using separate variables internally is the best one IMO.  But another option if that, for some reason, is untenable would be to keep a copy of the original value and restore it before invoking the sub-make, something like this:

```
_orig_MYVARIABLE := $(MYVARIABLE)
MYVARIABLE += change1

all:
        MYVARIABLE='$(_orig_MYVARIABLE)' $(MAKE) -f makefile2.mk
```

(just to note, you should never invoke a sub-make with the static string `make`; you should always use the variable `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}` if you prefer).